# Нужно ли ставить запятую в этом предложении перед "есть"?

Tags: пунктуация

> Во всех употребляемых тобой продуктах(,) есть витамины.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Во всех употребляемых тобой продуктах // есть витамины.***

1. Запятая, конечно, не нужна, но можно подумать о том, почему появляется желание поставить здесь запятую.

Ответить на этот вопрос можно только с помощью интонационного анализа. Простое предложение состоит из двух фраз, разделенных **произносительной паузой**, поэтому на месте этой паузы иногда ставят **"лишнюю запятую".**

2. А вот упрощать предложение нежелательно, иначе мы будем работать с другим предложением, а не  с тем, которое нам задано. Да и оценка **"становится понятно"** не является убедительной, доказательство должно выглядить как-то иначе.
3. ***Во всех продуктах // есть витамины.***

Структура предложения при упрощении  остается прежней. Здесь тоже **присутствует** произносительная пауза, но в распространенном варианте она подчеркнута в большей степени, в этом вся разница.

Answer (score 3):

Не нужно. Если упростить предложение до "Во всех продуктах есть витамины", то становится понятно, что запятая тут лишняя, отделять ничего не нужно.

Comment: В нашем случае упрощение — **не тот** метод для определения нужности-ненужности запятых. Представим, что перед нами другое (почти такое же) предложение: _Во всех продуктах, употребляемых тобой, есть витамины._ Мы его тоже можем упростить до указанной Вами конфигурации: _Во всех продуктах есть витамины._ Но это не означает, что запятые в указанном предложении не нужны.